# Are the links between the inode and data blocks of a file removed when deleting the file?

Tags: filesystems, rm, ext4, inode

Suppose there is only one hard link to a file. When `rm` the hard link, the inode and data blocks of the file will be marked as unused.

But are the links from the inode to the data blocks of the file removed or kept untouched until the inode is reused for another file?

If latter, how can I recover the deleted file?

I am using Ubuntu and ext4.

Comment: Have you tried using debugfs?